# How to define application family and signing key in IBM MobileFirst?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to do the data sharing between 2 apps (IBM MobileFirst),

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html%23setSharedToken

There is a requirement for the data sharing which is :
Saves a key/value pair such that it is available to other applications participating in simple shared data who are in the same application family, defined by the same family name and same application signing key.

May I know how to define application family and signing key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called "Simple Data Sharing", and there is a full use documentation umbrella for it. Have you read that first?

See here: [Simple data sharing](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_simple_data_sharing.html).
This covers the following topics: Overview, Terminology, Enablement, APIs and Troubleshooting, limitations and considerations.

You did not specify whether your requirement is for Hybrid apps or Native iOS/Android apps, so I suggest that you will first make you pick and follow the step-by-step instructons, here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_simple_data_sharing_enabling.html